# How to clone model in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, model, cakephp-1.3

I have some model category, that I need to clone. I know, that I can do it with copying getting existed one, unset its id property and save it. but it seems it`s not a good method to do it, if your model has some hasMany associations. Then you need to do such actions with model, save it and then do same things with all associations and save them.

Should I need to define method in model and then call it?

Can I get model like object and not like Array?

Are there any way to make it work something like this:

```
$category = $this->Category->find("first", array(
    'conditions' => array('categoryID' => $categoryID),
    'contain' => array('Connected')
));

$newCat = clone $category; 

$this->Category->save($newCat);
```

Comment: Something about this doesn't feel right. Why are you cloning? Are you trying to save the category you just took from the DB?

Answer (score 3):

In your code eg. you seem to be assuming that `$category` variable is an object when infact it's an array. So there's no question of cloning. Cake model's are not like active record instances. The just consume and produce arrays.

Elaborating.. To achieve what you need you would have to loop through all records in `$category` array and unset the primary key field (usually id) and then you can pass that array to Category->saveAll()